# Unresolved reference: ActivityLifecycleCallbacks

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, androidx, android-lifecycle

I am new in android development and stuck on building an existing project written in Java and Kotlin. I am upgrading the project by upgrading build system to Gradle 7 and compileSdkVersion 30. While building the project gradle forced to migrate to androidx so I enabled that by setting true for below flags

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Everything seems fine during build except it failing on the gradle task as below:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/User1/Documents/workspace/workspace1/src/TestApp/app/src/main/kotlin/com/amazon/ihm/testapp/lifecycle/TestAppLifecycleCallback.kt: (123, 32): Unresolved reference: ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
```

The source where it's breaking

```
package com.example.prc.testapp.lifecycle

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks

interface TestAppLifecycleCallback: ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, bundle: Bundle?) {}
    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {}
    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {}
    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {}
    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {}
    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, bundle: Bundle) {}
    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {}
}
```

breaking the import **import android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks**

build.gradle (dependencies) - app level

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.0.0'
```

I am using Kotlin = 1.5.x and also tried with different version lower than that but still having the same issue. Anyone give me some idea whats going on.